# How to prevent jekyll build on github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to upload a static HTML site to my user repo on github. However github detects it as a jekyll site and throws an error about build failing due to date format.

Is there any way to tell github to not try to build a repo and just serve it as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer -https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages

Just needed to include a `.nojekyll` file in the repo